# Web Service Serializing complex objects

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, web, known-types

I have a web service with `Class1`.  `Class1` has a List of images for a property

```
[Serializable]
[SoapInclude(typeof(Bitmap))]

public class Class1
{
    private static List<Image> _myList = new List<Image>();

    public List<Image> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }

        set
        {
            _myList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When doing a get on `MyList`, the below error happens.  Any ideas?

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error generating the XML document. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Drawing.Bitmap was
>   not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify
>   types that are not known statically.    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write4_Image(String
>   n, String ns, Image o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write5_Class1(String
>   n, String ns, Class1 o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write6_HelloWorldResponse(Object[]
>   p)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer1.Serialize(Object
>   objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle,
>   String id)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter,
>   Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues, Stream outputStream)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at the below URL.  I needed the [XmlInclude] tag instead of the [SoapInclude] tag

[Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx)

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Bitmap))]
    public class Class1
    {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example in the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapincludeattribute.aspx), I believe you have to apply the `[SoapInclude]` attribute on the actual SOAP WebService method:

```
public class MyService : WebService {

    [SoapInclude(typeof(Bitmap))]
    public List<Image> GetImageList() {
        // code here
    }

}
```

Comment: @mellamokb....I found an answer and posted it....give it a look.  I had [SoapInclude] instead of [XmlInclude]